# how to handle special character( in values) of matrix parameter - Spring REST URL

Tags: spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I need to pass `itemNumber1` value as `075/458`
http://localhost:8080/projectroot/some/itemNumber=075%2F458
 or
http://localhost:8080/projectroot/some/itemNumber=075/458

But this is not hitting my controller method:

```
@RequestMapping("/some/{number}")
public @ResponseBody void getSomething(
        @MatrixVariable(required = true) String itemNumber1,
        @MatrixVariable(required = false) String itemNumber2,
        @MatrixVariable(required = false) String itemNumber3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to parse it via the URL, but you are trying to get it by @ResponseBody. If you are using GET method to parse the value, your response body will be empty. If you try to get the data via response body, try the POST method instead.